# How to fix/reinstall SQL Express for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I try clicking "Show Table Data" in VS2010, I get this error message:

[image]

[image]

This started happening after I installed VS11 Beta and then uninstalling it. I tried uninstalling and reinstall VS2010, but it didn't fix the issue. Is there some way to force the re-installation of the SQL Express Plugin/Addin for VS2010?

I can't seem to find anything of the sort on the MS website, they keep touting [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx).